# listening help is necessary. native required

Tags: listening

[linked mp3 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11zzIIoPcxVV7JdCN2SebAqZZmEx6xq_b/view?usp=sharing)

the script of the linked mp3 file is "why <**does that**> look like egg?"
But I cant hear "that" at all.
And the sound of "does that" is weired.
is there a contraction of "does that"?
is it true that she pronounce "that"?

Comment: Yes, she does slur her words very much. I would write it as "Why's that", but even the _that_ is barely distinguishable.

Comment: I detect an English accent (from England in the UK specifically). She is saying "why does that look like egg".  It's an example of fast connected speech, and there's a glottal stop replacing the k of look and like, and the t of that.  It's almost as if she is saying: Whyza'loo'li'egg.  This is a fairly common speech pattern for the UK. I could even hazard a guess where she's from: I suspect somewhere in or near London, perhaps with a bit of an MLE accent.

Comment: @BillyKerr - yes to MLE. To this London-born native speaker, she is saying 'Why does that look like egg?' very clearly.

Comment: *That* is commonly reduced, as seen in spellings like "[wassat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wassat#English)" (what's that),

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, as another native Londoner I agree. it's clear to me even though spoken fast with some slurring.

Comment: Again, editing your question to remove your question is annoying and disrespectful. Don't do it! I have rolled back your edits to restore your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear quite clearly "Why does that look like egg?" in a certain British accent.

The /d/ is very short, but the pause in the stream of sounds makes me certain that there's a consonant there, not "Why's", unless she holds the vowel much longer than I'd expect. (The volume fades in from a lower level, so the already faint stop sound is harder to make out, but I don't think a different sound could have left the same ghost.)

The next three words end in glottal stops rather than their nominal final consonants: /ðæʔ lʊʔ lajʔ/ In fact, the stop on the last word cuts the diphthongization so short that it's almost /la/ rather than /laj/.

Note that the /z/ of "does" and the /ð/ of "that" are very close in articulation and you might have a hard time distinguishing both. To a native speaker, though, the /æ/ alone would be enough to tell you what word that must be in context!

The last word is pretty clear, but the voicing on the rather forceful /g/ drops away in time to give a /k/-like release.

Besides the faint /d/, the vocal acrobatics of her rapid-fire glottal stops instead of final plosives could certainly throw a person off, but when you're familiar with that accent, you know to expect that sound in that place. It would have been slightly harder, but far from impossible, to transcribe it without knowing what the script said.

Comment: "thx for ur"  There is a some irony that you ask about slurred, contracted and reduced speech,  but are happy to use use slured contracted and reduced text!